# Can I transfer files within HDFS using -put command?

Tags: shell, hadoop, command, put

Hadoop documentation says-
PUT-Copy single src, or multiple srcs from local file system to the destination file system

copyFromLocal - Similar to put command, except that the source is restricted to a local file reference.

Does it mean for -PUT source is NOT restricted to a local file reference and I can transfer files from HDFS to HDFS?

I did try this but could not success...

Please help , I am a complete newbie to Hadoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type this in terminal:

```
hdfs dfs -put /user/new/sample.txt /user/new1/sample.txt
```

This command will copy the file named `sample.txt` from hdfs directory `/user/new` to `/user/new1`. This is how you can copy a file to another location within HDFS.

**EDITED:**

```
hdfs dfs -cp /user/new/sample.txt /user/new1/sample.txt
```

This command will also copy files within HDFS.

Comment: I created a directory in root as /user/new and /user/new1 and created sample.txt in dir new.I tried your code but it says - /user/new/sample.txt does not exist. everytime I try to copy from HDFS to HDFS it says the same thing that the file after -put does not exist. I seems it is searching it in local file system. Did you try it?

Comment: First do this, `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /usr/sample.txt /user/new/`. `/usr/sample.txt` is your file in local disk and `/user/new/` is the hdfs directory to copy `sample.txt`. After this type, `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -ls /user/new/` to see if sample.txt is uploaded. Now, try the step in the answer. It will work.

Comment: I did exactly this-

hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/new .
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/new1 .
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/practice/mylocaldir1/movie.txt   /user/new/ .
hdfs dfs -ls /user/new .
** IT SHOWED THE RESULT AS**
 -rw-r--r--   3 hduser supergroup         25 2015-04-05 19:48 /user/new/movie.txt .

hdfs dfs -put /user/new/movie.txt /user/new1/movie.txt .

It still says "/user/new/movie.txt does not exist."

I am not using any distribution might it make a difference.and In my system the path of hadoop bin is already set so I run hadoop commands from any directory I am in.

Comment: What does this command results: `hdfs dfs -cat /user/new/movie.txt`?

Comment: Also try this: `hdfs dfs -cp /user/new/movie.txt /user/new1/movie.txt`

Comment: hdfs dfs -cat /user/new/movie.txt       is showing the movie names inside this  document.  And yes -cp is working. I guess -put does not support hdfs to hdfs copy.

Comment: `put` command works for me. Try `put` command with different filetype like csv to check if it works. For `cp` command, i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not find the answer yourself ?

```
xilan@slc07dko: ~/ords$ hdfs dfs -help copyFromLocal
-copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] <localsrc> ... <dst>:  Identical to the -put command.
```

put and copyFromLocal can be used to copy files from local file system to HDFS.

Use cp to copy files in HDFS or mv to rename/move. Just as what they in a Linux system.